# How can a parser and a lexer work together if they're in separate packages?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

This question concerns Antlr, the parser/lexer generator (Which is pretty awesome IMO). Specifically, the version in question is Antlr4. Currently I'm playing around trying to create a parser/lexer combo in separate files, which worked well at first.

However, when I tried to modularize the different components, for organization's sake, I discovered an issue. The two tools I'm using to modularize, package declarations in headers and setting the parser's token vocab, work perfectly separately, but I cannot seem to get them to play nice together.

I've put together a very short example that illustrates my issue.

First, I've defined my lexer:

```
lexer grammar UsefulLexer;

@header{
package org.useful.lexer;
}

USEFUL_TOKEN:'I\'m useful, I promise!';
```

Second I've defined my parser.

```
parser grammar UsefulParser;

@header{
package org.useful.parser;
}

options{
    tokenVocab=UsefulLexer;
}

usefulRule:USEFUL_TOKEN*;
```

But when I build, I get the useful error:

```
cannot find tokens file /Users/me/Desktop/Workspace/Project_Name/src-gen/org/useful/parser/UsefulLexer.tokens
```

All the rules together work perfectly together in a combined grammar, or even separately, provided they are in the same package. However, for how I'm using Antlr, with multiple parsers sharing the same lexer, having all the components in the same package defeats the purpose of using packages in the first place.

I've consulted the [docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+4+Documentation), especially the [section on grammar structure](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Grammar+Structure), and I can't find an official source for how to fix this. I've also tried the obvious solution, changing `tokenVocab=UsefulLexer` to `tokenVocab=org.useful.lexer.UsefulLexer`, but that doesn't even parse. (Which I find somewhat ironic.)

What is the syntax I am missing? Or is this just something that there isn't syntax for?

Comment: Works for me. Is there a chance that you have an old Antlr jar in your path?  Also, are you explicitly building the Lexer - have to build both the lexer and parser.

Comment: @GRosenberg What ANTLR version are you using? I'm using 4.5.

Comment: @GRosenberg and you have literally the same code in my question?

Comment: Literally.  Just a cut an paste of what you posted.  I get the error you mention if I do not explicitly build the Lexer.  Are you certain you are building both the lexer and parser?  Perhaps show your build command line.

Comment: @GRosenberg I'm actually using the ANTLR4 eclipse plugin, so that might be part of the issue... Can I see your command? [BTW I see that sneaky edit to your first comment ;)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to modify my ANTLR build command for both the lexer and the parser, adding the -lib & -package options. Once I pointed -lib at the package of my lexer in my parser buildscript, and moved my package declarations to the build commands in both, it was smooth sailing.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Have to build both the lexer and parser.  Here is a simple test rig builder:

```
@echo off
rem Execute the Antlr compiler/generator tool
rem put grammar files in "D:/DevFiles/Java/src/test/parser"

SETLOCAL

set files=../UsefulLexer.g4 ../UsefulParser.g4

set CLASSPATH=D:/DevFiles/Java/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar
set tool=org.antlr.v4.Tool

set cmd="C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe" 
set opts=-visitor

cd /d D:/DevFiles/Java/src/test/parser/gen
%cmd% %tool% %opts% %files%

ENDLOCAL

pause
rem timeout 5
```